# how to get table data from api using gatsby-ant-plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have created a simple table using ant table. I have tried to get the values from API but I am getting this exception:

> Unable to get property 'data' of undefined or null reference

my sample code is

```
import React from "react"
import { Table } from 'antd';

class StudentTable extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=200&nat=us")
      .then(Response => Response.json())
      .then(findresponse => {
        console.log(findresponse.results);
        this.setState({
          data: findresponse.result

        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        title: 'Gender',
        dataIndex: 'gender',
        key: 'gender',
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        key: 'email',
      }
    ]
    const data = []
    return(
      <div>
        <h2>Student Data</h2>
        <Table 
          dataSource={this.state.data}
          columns={columns}/>   
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default StudentTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't init a state in your component, so in the first render `this.state` is `null`.

If you're using Gatsby, you can probably init state like

```
class StudentTable extends React.Component {
  state = { data: ... };
  componentDidMount() { ... }
  ...
}
```

or do so in the constructor

```
class StudentTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { data: ... }
  }
  componentDidMount() { ... }
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you i am  getting the data from an api but i am getting this warning--->Warning: Each record in table should have a unique `key` prop,or set `rowKey` to an unique primary key.

Comment: that's a specific requirement from antd's table. Take a look at the [doc](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column), you'll see that each object in the `dataSource` array should have a `key` property.

Comment: @laxmi what you should do is to either loop over your api results and give each object an unique key based on some properties of that object. For example, in the results of your api, the property `login.uuid` is unique. You can use it as key for your data. Or, alternatively, do the set `rowKey` thing -- I'm not familiar with antd so I have no idea what that is!

Comment: Thank you.it's ok. I will try to this approach.

Comment: hi i have a simple form bit i did not get any idea how to  divide a table row and cols